# Prevent optimising jpeg on amazon s3

Tags: optimization, amazon-web-services, coldfusion, amazon-s3

I am uploading files to amazon s3 using this coldfusion:

```
<cfset localImage = imageRead("myImage")>
<cfset imageWrite(localImage, "s3://mybucket/#localImage#")>
```

But when I run the code to upload a 2MB file and then view the image in the amazon s3 management area it is optimizing the file to 825Kb. The problem is that I need the original to be stored there. Can I prevent amazon from optimizing it or is there something else I should be doing when uploading there. also is that coldfusion the best way to upload to amazon?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the best aproach to basically uploading an image.

Do a `<cffile action="copy">` instead. There is no need for you to parse the image if you are just moving it from one place to another.

Comment: doh! yeah, you are right. changing it to cffile is uploading the 2MB version. bit odd that the other way would be creating a smaller file size though?

Comment: I think ColdFusion is optimising it and saving it as a 80% optimised or something.